# pass variable values into variable

Tags: jquery

Essentially trying to add variables together, and then pass them into a final variable

```
//-- answers --//
var groupA1 = 0;
var groupA2 = 0;
var groupA3 = 0;

var answerQuestion1 = 0;

testButton.on('click', function () {
    answerQuestion1 = ((groupA1).val) + ((groupA2).val) + ((groupA3).val);
    console.log("I am being clicked");
    console.log(answerQuestion1);
    console.log(groupA1);
    console.log(groupA2);
    console.log(groupA3);

});
```

Anyone know why 'answerQuestion1' is consoling as 'NaN'?

Cheers

Comment: use `parseFloat()` or `parseInt()` to add numbers also use `val()` edit no need to add `.val()` since you are adding var. use `.val()` only to get value of input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

variable have not use with `.val` and use `parseInt` for calculation otherwise  "+" operator  for string concatenation.

```js
var groupA1 = 0;
var groupA2 = 0;
var groupA3 = 0;

var answerQuestion1 = 0;

$('#testButton').on('click', function() {
  answerQuestion1 = parseInt(groupA1) + parseInt(groupA2) + parseInt(groupA3);
  console.log("I am being clicked");
  console.log(answerQuestion1);
  console.log(groupA1);
  console.log(groupA2);
  console.log(groupA3);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='button' id='testButton'>
```

Comment: Thanks for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Use parseInt before adding, so that it will not concatenate as strings

```js
//-- answers --//
var groupA1 = 0;
var groupA2 = 0;
var groupA3 = 0;

var answerQuestion1 = 0;

$('button').on('click', function () {
    answerQuestion1 = parseInt($('[name="groupA1"]').val()) + parseInt($('[name="groupA2"]').val()) + parseInt($('[name="groupA3"]').val());
    console.log("I am being clicked");
    console.log(answerQuestion1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" value="3" name="groupA1">
<input type="number" value="2" name="groupA2">
<input type="number" value="1" name="groupA3">
<button>Compute</button>
```